# How can I show a Hit/Visits Counter on my page which uses Piwik for analytics

Tags: php, api, counter, matomo

I want to show the Visits for the current day on a homepage.
That page is tracked with Piwik.

How to use the API with PHP to get the (unique) visits and hits for today so that I can show them somewhere on the page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$result = file_get_contents("http://mysite.com/piwik/?module=API&method=VisitsSummary.getUniqueVisitors&idSite=1&period=day&date=today&format=php");
echo unserialize($result);
```

Comment: how to do this in php instead of the REST API?

Comment: What do you mean? This *is* php.

Comment: see this section `Call the Piwik API in PHP` in this page http://piwik.org/docs/analytics-api/calling-techniques/

Comment: I have a question on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238534/how-to-set-up-a-direct-piwik-api-calling-in-php/9239471#9239471 I have not looked at the answer there but I will check it now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's later answer but...

A few days ago I wrote a new plugin for Piwik which displays total visit and views on image for custom site for custom date range.

For more information please visit [http://киноархив.com/en/others/notes-on-html-jquery-php-mysql/10-piwik-graphical-counter.html](http://%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B2.com/en/others/notes-on-html-jquery-php-mysql/10-piwik-graphical-counter.html)

and post any information about bugs here [https://github.com/Globulopolis/Counter/issues](http://dev.piwik.org/trac/ticket/3153)