# Piwik: generate a counter image to display it on external sites

Tags: php, image, gd, counter, matomo

It is possible to generate a image (php gd) with a count of visitors of my piwik tracked site.
I want Embed a flag counter in a external site. On this page iframe or flash not allow. so i can't integrate the normal piwik widgets

Comment: Perhaps the first related question on the right is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786461/how-can-i-show-a-hit-visits-counter-on-my-page-which-uses-piwik-for-analytics

Comment: I need a php script (GD Library) that generate a **dynamic image** with piwik stats (daily visitors). Isn't there something like this yet?

Comment: Also see [Apache based Hit Counter with image banner?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/37357) on Software Recommendation Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the Piwik Widget functionnality to export the 'Graphs of last visits' widget anywhere (using iframe, or flash embed directly): http://piwik.org/docs/embed-piwik-report/