# how to set up a direct piwik API calling in php

Tags: php, matomo

I tried to do it this way but it gives this error:
`Fatal error: Class 'Piwik_FrontController' not found in C:\wamp\www\aqar2\piwik.php on line 11`

my website path is :`localhost/aqar2`
my piwik path is: `localhost/aqar2/piwik`

```
<?php
// if you don't include 'index.php', you must also define PIWIK_DOCUMENT_ROOT
// and include "libs/upgradephp/upgrade.php" and "core/Loader.php"
define('PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH', realpath('.localhost/aqar2/.'));
define('PIWIK_USER_PATH', realpath('.localhost/aqar2/.'));
define('PIWIK_ENABLE_DISPATCH', false);
define('PIWIK_ENABLE_ERROR_HANDLER', false);
define('PIWIK_ENABLE_SESSION_START', false);
require_once PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH . "piwik/index.php";
require_once PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH . "piwik/core/API/Request.php";
Piwik_FrontController::getInstance()->init();
// This inits the API Request with the specified parameters
$request = new Piwik_API_Request('
        method=UserSettings.getResolution
        &idSite=1
        &date=yesterday
        &period=week
        &format=XML
        &filter_limit=3
        &token_auth=&token_auth=a688c5c011dac27cf125eaa84f95e59b
');
// Calls the API and fetch XML data back
$result = $request->process();
echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

If your php file is in `localhost/aqar2/`then the path must be `define('PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH', realpath('piwik/'));`

I know you probably fixed it already so i am adding that for whoever may need it...

Answer (score 0):

That error is a result of a class being used (or referenced) but not yet loaded. This is likely a result of your PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH being incorrectly set, or that you are required to include the class yourself.

First, double check that the value set in your `PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH` is a valid path on the system, perhaps with:

```
if (is_dir(PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH)) {
  exit('IT IS A REAL PATH');
} else {
  exit('IT IS NOT A REAL PATH');
}
```

If it turns out to not be a real path, perhaps you should look at the '.' dot prefix on your 'localhost' directory. Do you not mean to use `realpath('localhost/aqar2/piwik');`. If that does work, you should also look at how you've set `PIWIK_USER_PATH`.

If that does not work, you should look at including the FrontController class yourself, but this may mean that you have to manually include all of that classe's dependencies as well. To include the class manually, use `include(PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH . '/core/FrontController.php');`

It would seem that directory structure you're trying to use is wrong, perhaps you should revise that and try to keep all files under the `localhost` directory.

Comment: I used this `define('PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH', realpath('piwik/'));` and it gave me a green light for your directory checking code.  I don't know what the user path is but I defined it the same as the include path. and it still gives me an error.`Warning: require_once(C:\wamp\www\aqar2\piwikindex.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\aqar2\piwik.php on line 16`  
` Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'C:\wamp\www\aqar2\piwikindex.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\aqar2\piwik.php on line 16`

Comment: It seems that your include path is still wrong. Perhaps this is a result of the directory structure being wrong. Could you edit your post to include your directory structure from your www directory?